# ForEach referencing CSV and Variable for Automated Boundary Removal

Tags: powershell, sccm

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"

Foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.Name |
        Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet } |
        Remove-CMBoundary -Verbose
}
```

The above code works perfectly to clear subnets from an sccm site. What i want to do though is, only remove 1 Site or Line in the CSV at a time - using a variable already entered.

So something like:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
$site = "London"

Foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.$site |
        Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet } |
        Remove-CMBoundary -Verbose
}
```

Comment: `Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $site | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $line.Subnet } | Remove-CMBoundary -Verbose` ?

Comment: @Paxz Thanks dude